# How include a requried packages inside my own package in R?

Tags: r

I built my own package and everything is working well. However, I need to load another packages when I load my package. That is, I want R loads all requires packages automatically when I load my package like this:

```
library(mypackage)
loading requrie packages:
first package 
second package
```

Is there any easy way?

Comment: [Here are the relevant docs.](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies) In most cases it's a good idea to minimize the `Depends` list, though; put what the package needs to function in `Imports` and let the user choose whether to load them explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add them in your `DESCRIPTION` file, section `Depends`.

```
Depends:
  first package,
  second package
```

You should read the book [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/).

Comment: I could not find `Depends` section in `DESCRIPTION` or do I need to add it manually?

Comment: Thank you so much.